# Dimensions of connected components of fixed point sets

Tags: finite-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, fixed-points

Assume a finite group $G$ acts smoothly on a connected manifold $M$. Is it true that all connected components of the fixed point set $M^G$ have the same dimension? If not in general, then maybe at least for $M$ being spheres? I am interested in some other result than the classical Smith theory of $p$-groups - in this case for $\mathbb{Z}_p$-homology spheres, the fixed point sets are $\mathbb{Z}_p$-homology spheres as well and thus connected.

Comment: Definitely need to assume M connected.

Comment: So far I found this [Paper by Frankel](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.agt/1513882415) dealing with the case of 3-manifolds, in which he states that fixed point sets are disjoint unions of closed geodesics.